# Inner join between tables, time consuming

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a SQL-query that takes way too long in my opinion, about 30 seconds as it looks now. I have two tables, `Record` and `Mainrecord`. I would like to get information about all the Mainrecords that has 0 in the column amount, and also in that case get the latest Record with the same Id that has something other then 0 in it's own amount. I have about 30,000 mainrecords and about 3,000,000 records. I guess that this can be optimized in some way but I cant figure it out.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    mainrecord
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tt.* 
        FROM record tt 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Max(record.timestamp) AS maxtimestamp, id 
            FROM record 
            WHERE record.amount <> 0 
            GROUP BY record.id
        ) AS rec 
        ON tt.id = rec.id AND tt.timestamp = rec.maxtimestamp
    ) AS t
    ON mainrecord.id = t.id
)
WHERE amount = 0
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |   table    |    type     | possible_keys |    key    | key_len |         ref         |  rows   | filtered |                 Extra                 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | Mainrecord | index_merge | Id,Amount     | Amount    |     768 | \N                  |    2850 |   100,00 | Using sort_union(Amount); Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ref         | key0          | key0      |     768 | db.Mainrecord.Id    |      53 |   100,00 | Using where                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tt         | ref         | Id,timestamp  | timestamp |       9 | record.maxtimestamp |      1  |   100,00 | Using where                           |
|  3 | DERIVED     | Record     | index       | Amount        | Id        |     768 | \N                  | 3185669 |    50,03 | Using where                           |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you any indices? Also please add `Explain` results to the question.

Comment: Who is mainrecord table!?

Comment: @Shaharyar, both id and amout are keys in both tables.

Comment: Can you add `Explain Extended` result as well?

Comment: @Shaharyar I have added that now

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

What about this? TO extract the grouping from subqueries

UPDATED:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mainrecord mr
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(record.timestamp) AS maxtimestamp, id 
        FROM   record 
        WHERE  record.amount <> 0 
        GROUP  BY record.id) AS max_r ON max_r.id=mr.id
    INNER JOIN record r ON mr.id = r.id
WHERE  mr.amount = 0 
  AND r.timestamp = max_r.maxtimestamp
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get this to work. I guess that the `FROM Record` should be `FROM record tt`. I also removed the `)` after `rec.maxtimestamp` since the amount of parenthesis didn't match. The error I get now is Syntax error on: `AS max_r ON max_r.id=mr.id INNER JOIN record r ON mr.id = r.id`

Comment: I can't check sytax properly. Please create SQlFiddle so I can test the query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/430e02/1/0 test with that, I added a very easy structure that contains all the elements that we use.

Comment: Thanks, the query now worked. Unfortunately the query took quite much longer (~4min), and also didn't limit the results to 1 per Id (the latest record that didn't have 0 amout).

Comment: Here is the explain for the query on the full data
`"1" "PRIMARY" "r" "ALL" "Id" \N \N \N "2135733" "100,00" "Using where"
"1" "PRIMARY" "<derived2>" "ref" "key1" "key1" "768" "db.r.Id" "10" "100,00" ""
"1" "PRIMARY" "mr" "eq_ref" "Id" "Id" "767" "db.r.Id" "1" "100,00" "Using where"
"2" "DERIVED" "Record" "index" \N "Id" "768" \N "2135733" "100,00" "Using where"`